# How can I get rid of the Evernote Web Clipper message?

Tags: pdf, evernote

Every time I open a PDF in Firefox there is a message from Evernote Web Clipper saying that I can save PDF into Evernote.

Can I get rid of this message without deinstalling Evernote Web Clipper?

[image: Evernote Web Clipper Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSC,
Click on your `Evernote` icon and click on `Options`.
After that you make sure that you've unchecked in `Show save to Evernote button on PDF pages.`
[Click to see option's page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7sfr.png)

Hope this helps